# Firebug : How to make net tab persistent?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

If I load new web page, the content of the old web page in net tab would all disappear.

Is there a way to make it persistent over different web page?

PS: I'm using Firebug 1.5.4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Jan Odvarko](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/f6a170f73054ba71):

> It's because of the following code in
>   tabWatcher.js

```
// xxxHonza, xxxJJB: web application detection. Based on domain check.
var prevDomain = persistedState ? getDomain(persistedState.location) :
null;
var domain = getDomain(location);
if (!persistedState || prevDomain != domain)
    persistedState = null;

If following is commented out, it works.
//if (!persistedState || prevDomain != domain)
//    persistedState = null;
```

Just as a note, If you are using Windows 7, the firebug extension directory path should be somethings like 'C:\Users\Jichao\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2dlypp9o.default\extensions\firebug@software.joehewitt.com\content\firebug'.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I wish this was possible, I don't think it is. Even if you clear the activation list of everything except for 1 web page, when you change tabs Firebug disappears. Even if you have it open in a separate window, it blanks out and gives you an "Activate" button.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug 1.7.a3+ supports this out of the box.

It is still in alpha stage, but it is available for install:

http://getfirebug.com/downloads